# Cat’s Neck - Fur Missing In Front

Tags: cats, hairloss, collar

I just noticed a large bald spot at the front of my 10 month indoor[image] Calico. It was not there yesterday. I removed her collar with a bell and charm as well as the Seresto collar. She has had both on for a couple months. She rubs her neck on furniture legs and door frames. The area is not wet or sticky; it is smooth and soft. I put Neosporin on it and touching it does not appear to bother her. I am not putting collars back on her. Has anyone else had this occur?  Thanks for any help.

Comment: did your vet recomend that you use neosporin on your cat? lots of medications used by people can be toxic if used on cats or dogs.

Comment: Neosporin is NOT SAFE to use on cats, applied to the skin not only can it cause irritation and allergic reactions, ibasically the opposite of what you want to achieve here, but it can also be dangerous if substantial quantities are ingested, e.g. when licking the treated area. See here: https://www.thesprucepets.com/is-neosporin-safe-for-cats-4768907

Comment: Just to prevent more potential problems: NEVER use any medication on cats that doesn't specifically say it's meant for cats on the packaging without consulting your vet first. You could unintentionally poison your cat. DON'T bathe your cat now to remove any traces of the Neosporin. Instead wipe her skin and fur with a wet washcloth dipped in warm water with a drop of washing up liquid. Bathing cats with human shampoo dries out their skin and can lead to itchy skin and hair loss.